# CSS Grids - Padding causes child element to overflow

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Here's my code:

```css
.media {
  display: grid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(50rem, 1fr));
}

.big-pic {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10rem;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.small-pic {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -.5rem;
  width: 50%;
  height: 10rem;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="media">
  <div class="column">
    <h2>On TV</h2>
    <div class="big-pic">
      Main Pic
    </div>
    <div class="small-pic">
      Pic 1
    </div>
    <div class="small-pic">
      Pic 2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <h2>In Theaters </h2>
    <div class="small-pic">
      Pic 1
    </div>
    <div class="small-pic">
      Pic 2
    </div>
    <div class="big-pic">
      Main Pic
    </div>
  </div>
```

When you lower the screen size of the browser, the child elements will overflow out of the container. Why is not the `column (a wrapper <div> with a class of column)` width not filling the parent's width?

I used `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(50rem, 1fr));` So 1fr should fill up the parent's width. When you add the padding, it overflows. Without the padding, it fills up the parent's width. Not sure what's happening.

Adding `box-sizing: border-box` doesn't fix the issue either. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: `50rem + 10rem*2 (1120px) > width of window`

Comment: instead of padding use grid-gap